# I am not getting a custom page size in memoir class. What is wrong?

Tags: page-breaking, memoir, geometry

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[pageheight= 94mm, pagewidth=195mm]{geometry}
\stockwidth\paperwidth
\stockheight\paperheight
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand\PlaceText[3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west] 
  at ([xshift=#1,yshift=-#2]current page.north west) {#3};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

%%number to words
\newcommand\majorUnit{Rupees}
\newcommand\minorUnit{Paisa}
\newcommand\spellOutCurrency[2]{%
    \NumToName{#1}\,\majorUnit\ and \NumToName{#2}\,\minorUnit%
}
% Load data from csv 
\usepackage{datatool}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Name, Amount 
John Doe, 1250
Tin Tin, 159

\end{filecontents*}




% Use custom date format
\usepackage{datetime,calc,tokcycle}
\Characterdirective{\addcytoks{#1\ }}
\newcommand{\customtoday}{\expandedtokcyclexpress
  {\twodigit{\the\day}\twodigit{\the\month}\the\year}\the\cytoks\unskip}
  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
% Load data.csv 
\DTLloaddb{list}{data.csv}
\DTLforeach{list}{%
\Name=Name,\Amount=Amount}

{\newpage

\thispagestyle{plain}
\PlaceText{15 cm}{0.75 cm}{ \customtoday}
\PlaceText{ 2 cm }{ 2 cm }{\Name }
\PlaceText{2 cm }{3.5 cm}{\spellOutCurrency{\Amount}{00}}
\PlaceText{15 cm}{3.8cm}{\Amount/-only}
}
\end{document}
```

I am not able to generate custom page size to print on a bank cheque. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: There is no `pageheight` and `pagewidth` options for `geometry`. I think you want `paperheight` and `paperwidth`. You may also want to add `\pagestyle{empty}` so that your cheque doesn't have a page number at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks. It simply did not occur to me

Comment: Another query if you can answer. Why I am getting only one page output for two rows in data.csv

Comment: You need to put your `\newpage` command at the end of the executed block not at the beginning, i.e. after your `\PlaceText` commands.

Comment: I've combined both my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. First, there is no `pageheight` and `pagewidth` option in `geometry`; you need to use `paperheight` and `paperwidth`.  Second, you need to place your `\newpage` command at the end of the executed block, not at the beginning. It also seems a little odd to use `\pagestyle{plain}` as opposed to `{empty}` but that depends on whether numbering the cheques like this is what you actually want.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[paperheight= 94mm, paperwidth=195mm]{geometry}
\stockwidth\paperwidth
\stockheight\paperheight
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand\PlaceText[3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west] 
  at ([xshift=#1,yshift=-#2]current page.north west) {#3};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

%%number to words
\newcommand\majorUnit{Rupees}
\newcommand\minorUnit{Paisa}
\newcommand\spellOutCurrency[2]{%
    \NumToName{#1}\,\majorUnit\ and \NumToName{#2}\,\minorUnit%
}
% Load data from csv 
\usepackage{datatool}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Name, Amount 
John Doe, 1250
Tin Tin, 159

\end{filecontents*}




% Use custom date format
\usepackage{datetime,calc,tokcycle}
\Characterdirective{\addcytoks{#1\ }}
\newcommand{\customtoday}{\expandedtokcyclexpress
  {\twodigit{\the\day}\twodigit{\the\month}\the\year}\the\cytoks\unskip}
  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
% Load data.csv 
\DTLloaddb{list}{data.csv}
\DTLforeach*{list}{%
\Name=Name,\Amount=Amount}
{\thispagestyle{plain}
\PlaceText{15 cm}{0.75 cm}{ \customtoday}
\PlaceText{ 2 cm }{ 2 cm }{\Name }
\PlaceText{2 cm }{3.5 cm}{\spellOutCurrency{\Amount}{00}}
\PlaceText{15 cm}{3.8cm}{\Amount/-only}
\newpage}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]